# Loop through the 100 different file names and outputs the "A1" value from each file

Tags: excel, vba

VBA question:

I have 100 different excel workbooks with a unique value in "A1"
I want to list all 100 in just one workbook.

That one workbook has the 100 file names listed in column A and I want to have the corresponding "A1" value from each respective workbook in column B right next to the file name in column A.

Can I create a macro that loops through the 100 file names and outputs the "A1" value from each file?

Comment: Yes, you can... But "the file" does not have a "A1" range. Do the workbooks in discussion have a single sheet? If not, will that necessary "A1" cell be in its first sheet?

Comment: Do you know the name of the sheet where to return from?

Comment: Yes, each only has 1 sheet "Sheet 1"

Comment: I did not see your comment before posting the answer. Which open each workbook and extract the date from "A1". But knowing the sheet name, I can make a faster piece of code, extracting the necessary value without opening the workbook...

Comment: Are you sure that the sheet name is "Sheet 1" and not the strandard "Sheet1" (without space...)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, try the next code:

```
Sub BringA1Val()
   Dim sh As Worksheet, wb As Workbook, lastR As Long, arr, arrRes, strPath, i As Long
    
    Set sh = ActiveSheet
    lastR = sh.Range("A" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row
    arr = sh.Range("A1:A" & lastR).Value2  'place the range in an array for faster iteration
    ReDim arrRes(1 To UBound(arr), 1 To 1) 'redim the array to keep the processed result

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False: Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
     For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
        If Dir(arr(i, 1)) <> "" Then
           Set wb = Workbooks.Open(arr(i, 1))
           arrRes(i, 1) = wb.Worksheets(1).Range("A1").value
           wb.Close , False
        Else
           arrRes(i, 1) = "Wrong file path..."
        End If
     Next i
     sh.Range("B1").Resize(ubound(arrRes), 1).value2 = arrRes
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True: Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

**Edited**:

Please, try the next version which does not need opening the workbook. But it will search for a sheet named "Sheet1". If its  name should be "Sheet 1" (space included), please modify it:

```
Sub BringA1ValNoOpenWb()
   Dim sh As Worksheet, wbPath As String, wbName As String, lastR As Long, arr, arrRes, strPath, i As Long
    
    Set sh = ActiveSheet
    lastR = sh.Range("A" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row
    arr = sh.Range("A1:A" & lastR).Value2
    ReDim arrRes(1 To UBound(arr), 1 To 1)
    
     For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
        If Dir(arr(i, 1)) <> "" Then
           wbPath = left(arr(i, 1), InStrRev(arr(i, 1), "\"))      'the wb path
           wbName = Right(arr(i, 1), Len(arr(i, 1)) - Len(wbPath)) 'the wb name
           
           arrRes(i, 1) = CellVal(wbPath, wbName, "Sheet1", "R1C1")
        Else
           arrRes(i, 1) = "Wrong file path..."
        End If
     Next i
     sh.Range("B1").Resize(ubound(arrRes), 1).value2 = arrRes
End Sub

Private Function CellVal(fPath As String, fName As String, SheetName As String, strRange As String) As Variant
   Dim strForm As String
    strForm = "'" & fPath & "[" & fName & "]" & SheetName & "'!" & strRange
    CellVal = Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro(strForm)
End Function
```

Comment: That works very fast, thank you very much.

Comment: @vbata22 Which "That"? Did you test the second version, too?

Comment: @vbata22 Please, test now the second version. Initially, I missed posting the function using `ExecuteExcel4Macro`...

Comment: It did not work like the first one, also missing a ' for "the wb name" comment. There was no error message with the ', but no data was output

Comment: @vbata22 yes, I missed the comment character ('). Corrected... What name has the sheet where from the value must be extracted? It maybe is "Sheet 1" as you said, and must be changed...

Comment: I added this line and now the code works perfectly:                                                 
         Cells(i, 2).Value = arrRes(i, 1) ' Output the value

Comment: @vbata22 No, not the best way. I deleted by mistake exactly the line which drops the processed array. The code will not only work, it will be clearly faster... I will do it immediately...